# Modal box doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

Ok so I am trying to open `abc.html` file ( placed in same directory ) in modal box.

This is the code but it doesn't seem to work. Please help

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a#someId").on("click", function(){
        $.post("abc.html", function(data){
    $("#myModalDiv").html(data).fadeIn();
    });
    });
});
 </script>
</head> 
<body>        
    <a id="someId" href="">This is a link to abc.html</a>
    <div id="myModalDiv">

    </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you loading jQuery 1.3 **and** 1.7? How about just loading the newest version instead.

Comment: Why are you including two version of jQuery ? Use only 1

Comment: I have edit it. Still not working.

Comment: Are you using code from a tutorial? If so, could you provide a link to that?

Comment: I have a tutorial as well. It would be great if you could figure out why is the Example4 doesn't work when run in file system(It works good only on website).  This is best alternative solution to my question. Here is its link [link](http://kylefox.ca/jquery-modal/examples/index.html) @Ziggy

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **[e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)** here to prevent default action of your anchor:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#someId").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("abc.html", function (data) {
            $("#myModalDiv").html(data).fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

Also, because `id` is unique, you just need to use `#someId` instead of `a#someId`.

Comment: Are you sure `jquery-1.11.0.js` is loaded properly? Try to use an `alert` when you click on the anchor to check whether it works or not. Also check to see is there any error in the browser console.

Comment: Jquery is loaded perfectly. I have used `alert` in place of this code and alert popped up. So the problem lies in here which I replaced by alert:

`e.preventDefault();
        $.post("abc.html", function (data) {
            $("#myModalDiv").html(data).fadeIn();
        });`

Comment: Try to use `$("#myModalDiv").html(data).hide().fadeIn();` instead of `$("#myModalDiv").html(data).fadeIn();`

Comment: Still no success brother.

Comment: It says on firbug console: `TypeError: e is null`

Comment: Did you pass `e` to the click function `$("#someId").on("click", function (e) {`?

Comment: Yeah I passed `e` to the click function. I actually have copied your code and replaced it.

Comment: I got it. I am new to AJAX. I requires to run in localhost server. I placed files in www directory of wamp server and it worked for me. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KhMuV/2/) of your working code.

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $("a#someId").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/echo/html/',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                html: "<p>Hey</p>"
            },
            success: function(data){
              $("#myModalDiv").html(data).fadeIn();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

As far as I can tell, you've got it mostly right. As you can see, clicking on the link fires an ajax request, which populates your div. The same code is given above in Felix' answer, but you said this doesn't work for you. This leads me to wonder exactly what "doesn't work".

Does the response (data) appear in the div? If so, are you concerned about the "fadeIn" effect? Or the modal box?

z.

Comment: Actually this piece of code doesn't work:

`e.preventDefault();
        $.post("abc.html", function (data) {
            $("#myModalDiv").html(data).fadeIn();
        });`

also, response data doesn't appear in div. I am concerned about modal box.

Comment: OK, but you see that the fiddle I provided does work, right? In that case, I think your problem might be that "abc.html" doesn't exist. Are you running a server, or is this code running in your file system? (when I say "doesn't exist" I mean "can't be found")

Comment: I am running it in my file system. 

Mean while `<a id="someId" href="abc.html"></a>` works prefect.

Comment: I got it. I am new to AJAX. I requires to run in localhost server. I placed files in www directory of wamp server and it worked for me. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yay! I'm glad you got it working. That's the sort of bug that can be really tough to track down. Good luck out there!